# codeigniter active record 'inner' join

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
query('SELECT * FROM answers INNER JOIN questions 
      WHERE answers.answerId= questions.questionId AND answers.answerId IN (' . $id . ')')
```

I need help to change this to active record for codeigniter.

i tried to get the values which is equal to the id form the two tables and join it. but when i tried like this

```
$this->db->select("*"); $this->db->join("questions","questions.questionId = answers.answerId"); $this->db->where_in('answers.answerId',$id); $res = $this->db->get("answers");
```

It's only displaying the first joined table passed through the id.

Comment: Hi Kohli, Welcome to stackoverflow, please provide some explanation what is issue.

Comment: @WoodChopper i tried to get the values which is equal to the id form the two tables and join it. but when i tried like this
 `$this->db->select("*"); 
 $this->db->join("questions","questions.questionId = answers.answerId");
 $this->db->where_in('answers.answerId',$id);
 $res = $this->db->get("answers");` It's only displaying the first joined table passed through the id.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('answers'); 
    $this->db->join('questions','questions.questionId=answers.answerId');
    $this->db->where_in('answers.answerId',$id);
    $query=$this->db->get();
    $result=$query->result();
```

Comment: i tried this but it's only displaying the one row table matched to the first id passed through the `where_in ` clause

Answer (score 0):

By default, its inner join

```
 $this->db->select("*");
 $this->db->join("questions","questions.questionId = answers.answerId");
 $this->db->where_in('answers.answerId',$id);
 $res = $this->db->get("answers");
```

Comment: I tried like that but it's only displaying the first id's table passed through  `where_in `where_in active record